# Spring security UserDetails and controller (get user)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

There is **UserDetail** and **LoginController**.

**UserDetail** gets the user from the database.

**UserDetail**

```
    public class UserDetail implements UserDetailsService {

        private final
        UserServiceJpa userServiceJpa;

        public UserDetail(UserServiceJpa userServiceJpa) {
            this.userServiceJpa = userServiceJpa;
        }


        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {


            // Get user
            User user = userServiceJpa.findUserByEmail(email);


            if (user == null){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no such user " + email);
            }


            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    user.getEnabled(),
                    user.getAccount_non_expired(),
                    user.getCredentials_non_expired(),
                    user.getAccount_non_locked(),
                    getAuthorities());

        }


        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

            return authList;

        }

    }
```

**LoginController**

```
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {


        @GetMapping(value = "/login")
        public String login () {

            return "/login";
        }

    }
```

***Question***! How in **LoginController** get this user, which was received by **UserDetail**?

I do this in order not to reconnect to the database. Thus, I want to know how the user was blocked if he was blocked - **enabled**, **accountNonExpired**, **credentialsNonExpired**, **accountNonLocked**

Answer (score -1):

You can create a UserDetails class from your LoginController by Autowiring it, and then call the function in your login class.

```
 @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login (@QueryParam("email")String email) {
        userDetails.loadUserByUsername(email);
        return "/login";
    }

}
```